# How do I join two tables based on the ids stored in a related table with SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table "books" with columns `id, title, length`. I have another table of genres with `id,name`. Finally, I have a third table that used to related the two called bookGenres with columns `id,bId,gId`.

I want to run a select query that gets genres and books based on the bookGenres table.

I tried something like

```
SELECT 
book.name AS bookName,
book.length AS bookLength,
genres.name AS bookGenre
FROM
book
LEFT JOIN bookGenres ON book.id = bookGenres.bId
LEFT JOIN bookGenres ON genres.id = bookGenres.gId
```

but that doesn't return any results. I got an error that genres.name isn't a column. When I remove it I'm told `bookGenres.bId` is an ambiguous column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't joining on genres, you were joining twice on bookGenres

```
SELECT 
book.name AS bookName,
book.length AS bookLength,
genres.name AS bookGenre
FROM book
LEFT JOIN bookGenres ON book.id = bookGenres.bId
LEFT JOIN genres ON genres.id = bookGenres.gId
```